# SftpClient Unit test derived class and mock base class C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, sftp, wrapper

I have a wrapper around `Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpClient`. I want to unit test this wrapper.

**my wrapper**

```
public class MySftpClient: SftpClient, IMySftpClient
{
    public MySftpClient(string host, int port, string username, string password) : base(new PasswordConnectionInfo(host, port, username, password)) { }

    public new void Connect()
    {
        base.Connect();
    }
}
```

**unit test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Connect_Successful_Valid()
{
    var mySftpClient = new MySftpClient("localhost", 22, "root", "password");

    mySftpClient.Connect();
    // This errors because it actually tries to connect to a server using the above mock connection data
    // I cannot assert method Connect() was called once.
}
```

1. Can I mock the base class method? Or should I make an interface around the SftpClient and inject it into the constructor of MySftpClient, prefering composition over inheritance?
2. Should I use .Net DI Injection for SftpClient?
   `services.AddScoped<ISftpClient, SftpClient>();`

**possible solution**

```
public class MySftpClient: IMySftpClient
{
    private ISftpClient sftpClient;

    public MySftpClient(
        ISftpClient sftpClient,
        string host,
        int port,
        string username,
        string password
    ) { // Instantiate PasswordConnectionInfo... }

    public void Connect()
    {
        sftpClient.Connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. "Or should I make an interface around the SftpClient and inject it into the constructor of MySftpClient, prefering composition over inheritance?" Yeap. 2. "Should I use .Net DI Injection for SftpClient? services.AddScoped<ISftpClient, SftpClient>();" Which (or if at all) DI-container you're using is up to you.

Comment: It seems I cannot pass `PasswordConnectionInfo` to the interface ISftpClient. The interface has no Connect method to help me check connection or pass credentials. If you know any suggestion. The interface ISftpClient is from Renci.SshNet, it's not mine. I cannot make SftpClient implement some interface of my own.

Comment: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/193
I have found this exact same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution at the moment is to exclude our own `SftpClient` wrapper from unit test coverage.
https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/890#issuecomment-957179713

A pull request was merged with an interface having Connect() method. But currently it is not merged into master.
https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/pull/975

[image: SftpClientWrapper]